# How to solve coupled differential equation of expansion coefficients numerically?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve the following set of coupled differential equations for $C_{n}$s numerically:

$\frac{dC_{n}(t)}{dt}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}f_{m,n}(t)C_{m}(t)$

How should I code this in Mathematica?

Comment: Should `f(t)` be `f_m(t)`, or can it be taken outside the sum?  I think you need to provide some more information about the assumed behaviour and boundary conditions of your functions.

Comment: @mikado I corrected the post. I don't need to know how to solve it right now. I want to know that how can I code it. I know how to use NDSolve for usual differential equations. But What about this type?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Let's assume that $n=1,2$ and $m=1,2$. How can I transform it to canonical form? Can you provide a minimal code?

Comment: My earlier comment was wrong.  Sorry.  However, for a finite number of equations, `NDSolve[Thread[D[c, t] == c.f, bc], c, {t, tmin, tmax}]` should work provided equations are not singular or stiff.  Here, `c` is vector of dependent variables,`f` is matrix of coefficients, and `bc` is vector of initial conditions.  An infinite number of equations cannot be solved numerically in finite time except under unusual circumstances.